# cómo cerrar un jframe sin cerrar la aplicacion en java si marco dato incorrecto?

Tags: java, poo, java-swing, jframe, netbeans-8.2

Tengo creados unos Jframe en java, un login, uno donde debe intro ducir codigo, precio, valor unitario y eso lo muestro en una tabla que es otro Jframe, lo que quiero saber es por ejemplo: cuando el usuario ponga en precio alguna letra el programa se cierre, ya que en precio solo se permiten números, ya tengo una opcion que si introduce numero le salga error, pero lo que quiero saber es como hago para que se cierre. Se me olvido decir que el código y eso lo guarda en un archivo, y también que al equivocarse no lo guarde

Answer (score 0):

Puedes utilizar el evento KeyTyped del JTextField el cual al pulsar una tecla obtiene el valor  con evt.getKeyChar() y verifica si has pulsado una letra o numero y procedera a cerrar el jframe en el caso de pulsar una letra.

```
private void txtKeyTyped(java.awt.event.KeyEvent evt) {
    char data= evt.getKeyChar();
     if (data < '0' || data> '9') {
       this.setVisible(false);
    }
}
```